# Javascript Nodes click order

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

I have one problem with Javascript Nodes.I want to find out what button was clicked and how many times..

So... There's example.

```
 <body>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>

  <p id="last-counted"></p>

</body>

<script>
   var body = document.body;
   var lastcounted = document.getElementById('last-counted');
   lastcounted.innerHTML = "test";
   // console.log(body.nodeName = 'button');
   console.log(body);
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your example doesn't show anything related to your question!

Comment: Where u have attached event handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is something you want -

http://jsfiddle.net/78GaP/

CODE:

```
  <button data-index='1' onclick='javascript:log(this)'></button>
  <button data-index='2' onclick='javascript:log(this)'></button>
  <button data-index='3' onclick='javascript:log(this)'></button>
  <button data-index='4' onclick='javascript:log(this)'></button>
  <button data-index='5' onclick='javascript:log(this)'></button>
  <button data-index='6' onclick='javascript:log(this)'></button>
  <button data-index='7' onclick='javascript:log(this)'></button>

  <p id="last-counted"></p>

<script>
var body = document.body;
var lastcounted = document.getElementById('last-counted');

var stat = {};
function log(t){
    var index = t.getAttribute('data-index');
    if(!stat.hasOwnProperty(index)){
        stat[index] = 0;        
    }
    stat[index] ++;
    console.log(stat);
}    
</script>​
```

Comment: @JakubKontra: If an answer solved your issue, make sure to accept it by clicking the big check-mark.